# What is the obstruction to extending a linear map on tangent spaces of a variety to a regular map on neighborhood?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties of the same dimension $n$. If $p$ and $q$ are points in $X$ and $Y$ respectively, suppose that there is a linear map $i : T_p X \to T_q Y$.

My vague question is this: What is the obstruction to "extending" $i$ to a map on Zariski open neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$, $f : U \to V$, with $df_p = i$?

I ask this question because I have just learned a result in Riemannian geometry that could be interpreted as saying that curvature is the obstruction in the Riemannian case. (Do Carmo Riemannian Geometry pg. 157). In that setting one uses strongly the existence of exponential maps and parallel transport (and curvature!), so I don't expect anything to carry over literally. I am just curious if one can make a connection in this way.

I know that one can always extend when the map $i$ is replaced by an $k$-algebra isomorphism of the germ of functions at those points.  (This is exercise 4.7 in Hartshorne.) So in a way I am asking the following commutative algebra question:

If $(R,M)$ and $(S,N)$ are local $k$-algebras admitting an $k$-linear isomorphism $N/N^2 \to M/M^2$, what is the obstruction to extending this to an isomorphism of $R$ to $S$?

Comment: Very interesting question! I think I'd prefer your original formulation, over the one in your last sentence. There you have isomorphisms between any two smooth $k$-schemes (at least at closed points), and you're asking fi they are birational. I think you should be restricting to just a morphism on the tangent spaces and getting a morphism on the local rings. As an example, if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective curves over $k$, then for any two $k$-points $p\in X$ and $q\in Y$ you obviously have that $T_p X\cong T_p Y$, but of course $X$ and $Y$ are never birational (unless they are equal).

Comment: I also think that a more informed question to ask is when can you extend to formal neighborhoods. Namely, when you have a map $T_p X\to T_p Y$ when can you extend this to a map $\mathrm{Spec}(\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}})\to \mathrm{Spec}(\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}})$. This is more in the spirit of your differential geometry analogue. Asking for maps on Zariski neighborhoods is just too strong. But, then, not shockingly this is a much easier question. In particular, by some sort of Cohen structure theorem argument, I think the answer is generally 'usually' for smooth things.

Comment: In fact, maybe always? Namely, $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$ should be isomorphic to the completion of $\mathrm{Sym}(T_p^*X)$ in a canonical way, which should give you the map. I mean, I guess what you really get is a map on on $\mathrm{gr}^\bullet\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ which one can easily upgrade to map on the formal neighborhoods.

Comment: Did you ever think of anything about this?